# Junit Unable to return mocked Response and return as null

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I m new to Mockito and trying to mock the webservice responses, I did tried mocking at some extent few Objects got worked, But the end mocked WebResponse is always returning null.

Service Method i am going to test:getWebResponse Method

```
public WebResponse getWebResponse(String crmNumber) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, WebException {
    Map<String, String> HEADERS_POST = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put(WebUtil.HEADER_CONTENT, WebUtil.CONTENT_JSON);
            put(WebUtil.HEADER_ACCEPT, WebUtil.CONTENT_JSON);
        }
    };
    JSONObject requestJson = new JSONObject();
    requestJson.put("crmNumber", crmNumber);
    requestJson.put("application", "ABCD");
    requestJson.put("feature", "DDDFL");
    // Using internal web service becuase device authentication is done separately.
    String url = CommonUtil.getServiceBaseUrl(true) + "/ett";
    WebServiceClient client = WebServiceClientRegistry.getClient(ApacheCustom.class);
    WebRequest webReq = new GenericWebRequest(WebRequestMethod.POST, url, HEADERS_POST, requestJson.toString());
    // Till here i m getting all mocked object (client also Mocked) after this stament the webRes is returning null;
    WebResponse webRes = client.doRequest(webReq);
    return webRes;
}
```

And here the test Method:

```
@Test
public void getWebResponseTest() {
    mockStatic(CommonUtil.class);
    mockStatic(WebServiceClientRegistry.class);
    this.webResponse = new GenericWebResponse(200, "", new HashMap(), "");

    try {
        Mockito.when(CommonUtil.getServiceBaseUrl(true)).thenReturn("https://stage.com/service");
        WebRequest webReq = new GenericWebRequest(WebRequestMethod.POST, "https://stage.com/service", new HashMap(), "");
        Mockito.when(WebServiceClientRegistry.getClient(ApacheCustom.class)).thenReturn(client);
        Mockito.when(client.doRequest(webReq)).thenReturn(this.webResponse);
        WebResponse wesponse = this.ServiceResponse.getWebResponse("Number");
        Assert.assertEquals(wesponse.getStatusCode(), 200);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

**But the getWebResonse method from Test class always returning null Response(Even Though it is mocked)**

Answer (score 0):

You mock `client.doRequest` as follows:

```
Mockito.when(client.doRequest(webReq)).thenReturn(this.webResponse);
```

but you create a new instance of WebRequest in your service under test.

You call doRequest with a different argument than recorded in your test.
Arguments are compared with equals.
Most likely WebRequest does not override equals, so recorded interaction is ignored and a default response (null) is rerurned.

I guess WebResuest may not be the code you own (you haven’t specified this in your question), so it may be impossible to override it.

Thus, you can use a different argument matcher.
You can use `ArgumentMatchers.any()` for good start, or implement a custom argument matcher.

Comment: Tried with the exact request object and Mockito.matchers, but could n't able to sucussed.